# Custom query parameters passing - Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to write custom query in JPA and for this I supposed to pass parameter as dynamic to the query.

This is the how my query is written:

```
@Repository
public interface Udata_Repository  extends JpaRepository<UTable, String>  {

@Query(value = "select B_Id from U_Data where T_Id = :tid", nativeQuery = true)
    List<String> find_Tid(@Param("tid") String tid);
}
```

But parameter is not going to set properly..

Comment: Have you checked the query log that the parameter is not set in query?

Comment: Yeah I checked the parameter is not going to set and it is coming like this
select B_Id from U_Data where T_Id = ?

Comment: Are the `@Query` and `@Param` imported from the correct package ? 
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

Comment: Does the alias change anything? change the query like: `@Query(value = "select u.B_Id from U_Data u where u.T_Id = :tid", nativeQuery = true)`

Comment: @SebastianCăşvean yeah imports are correct only

Comment: @Shafiul No alias changes i think..yeah i tried to use with alias name also, but still param not set

Comment: Can you show us the "U_Data" table structure ?

Comment: Can you try using ?1 instead of @Param and :tid?  Just to check whether something basic is going wrong.